# Is there a way to test a Android Sender app for Chromecast using the SDK's Android emulator?

Tags: google-cast

Without support for Google Play Services and WiFi (similar to the 3G network support, through the host's network connection), the SDK's emulator is useless for Chromecast app development. I know we can use real hardware, but some things are simpler using the emulator, especially quickly testing changes on a wide range of devices.

We're about to start developing the iOS version, here's hoping the Apple emulator is better!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about foretelling the future.

Comment: Google employees monitor and respond to questions posted under this tag, or at least they did prior to the recent Chromecast SDK release, hence the reasonable possibility that I'll get an answer.

Comment: It is a question that has very limited scope (only those Google employees that are actively involved in release schedules), and unless it's been announced on the Android website it's not publicly available information. Additionally, the question has no future value - once the support has been added, the question becomes meaningless. Wasn't asking for a debate, anyway; I've cast my vote to close for the reason indicated, and the comment is just a courtesy.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is with the mDNS discovery that is not supported on the emulator. We currently have no plans to work on that (this is copied from my comment, made it an answer and removed the old answer that was irrelevant).

Update: Cast discovery now is supported in the emulator.

Comment: I was asking about developing and testing an Android Sender app using the SDK's Android emulator. Not about emulating the Chromecast itself.

Comment: Oh, ok. In that case, the main issue is with the mDNS discovery that is not supported on the emulator. We currently have no plans to work on that.

Comment: @AliNaddaf been trying to connect to chromecast from emulator, I have the PC (running emulator) and ChromeCast on the same network. Other 'real' devices on the same network are able to discover the chromecast.

Comment: It maybe worth mentioning the emulator is API 27 x86 image.

Comment: How to use AndroidTV Google emulator as a Cast receiver?

Comment: Is it possible to emulate chromecast device itself ?

Comment: @AliNaddaf please if possible elaborate a bit more on de mDNS part, I've been testing on Android 11 emulator and it can't discover cast devices.